# Python: Average specific elements in a third array by the indexes of duplicate pairs of long and lat in two other arrays

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, average, matching

I have three separate arrays: longitude, latitude and current_speed.

The elements along each row of the arrays are matched i.e. at (long_1, lat_1) speed is equal to current_speed_1, at (long_n, lat_n) speed is equal to current_speed_n

Pairs of long and lat are duplicated throughout the arrays, however not at equal intervals e.g.

long_1, lat_1, current_speed_1

long_2, lat_2, current_speed_2

....., ...., ......

....., ...., ......

long_1, lat_1, current_speed_n

I would like to take positional average of the speeds at each repeated pair of (long, lat) i.e. take and average of all the speeds at (long_1,lat_1).

This requires finding each repeated pair, finding their index value and averaging all the indexes of speed for that pair.

I have attempted this using nested loops and appending to new arrays however this does not seem like a very pythonic way of achieving this and gets complex very quickly. I unfortunately do not know enough python to think of a cleaner way, does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is store each pair of unique lat,long as input of dictionary and consider all the speeds for these latitudes and longitudes. for example.

```
>>> lat = [1,2,3,1]
>>> long = [7,8,9,7]
>>> speed = [20,50,29,49]
>>> data = {}
>>> for i in range(len(lat)):
...     try:
...         data[(lat[i],long[i])].append(speed[i])
...     except KeyError:
...         data[(lat[i],long[i])]=[speed[i]]
... 
>>> data
{(2, 8): [50], (3, 9): [29], (1, 7): [20, 49]}
```

After this you can calculate average easily.

Comment: Cheers, works nicely. 
To average the data I used:    
    avg_data={} 
    for k,v in data.iteritems():
        avg_data[k]=sum(v)/float(len(v))